# OpenGL translation without glPush and glPop through shaders.

Tags: opengl

I don't quite understand how you do movement in OpenGL without using glPopMatrix and glPushMatrix. I can only get it to work by calling glDrawArray on several VAOs.

In this example below, I can move one triangle by using the shaders to do matrix multiplication. What I don't understand is say I have several points array I.e. points2[], points3[]. How would I go about being able to do translation without having to draw several VAOs? So how do I put everything into one VAO and still be able to say just multiple matrix3[] with points3[]?

```
float points[] = {
        0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.5f,  0.0f,
        0.5f, 0.5f,  0.0f,
        0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
        0.5f, 0.0f,  0.0f,
            0.5f, 0.5f,  0.0f
        };
float matrix[] = {
      1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, // first column
      0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, // second column
      0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // third column
      0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f // fourth column
    };

    unsigned int points_vbo = 0;
    glGenBuffers (1, &points_vbo);
    glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, points_vbo);
    glBufferData (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 18 * sizeof (float), &points, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
unsigned int vao = 0;
glGenVertexArrays (1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray (vao);
glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, points_vbo);
glVertexAttribPointer (0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (GLubyte*)NULL);
glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colours_vbo);
glVertexAttribPointer (1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (GLubyte*)NULL);

glEnableVertexAttribArray (0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray (1);

//Setup shaders
std::string vertex_shader = loadshaders("test_vs.txt");
std::string fragment_shader = loadshaders("test_fs.txt");

unsigned int vs = glCreateShader (GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
const char* str = vertex_shader.c_str ();
glShaderSource (vs, 1, &str, NULL);
glCompileShader (vs);
unsigned int fs = glCreateShader (GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
const char* strb = fragment_shader.c_str ();
glShaderSource (fs, 1, &strb, NULL);
glCompileShader (fs);

unsigned int shader_programme = glCreateProgram ();
glAttachShader (shader_programme, fs);
glAttachShader (shader_programme, vs);
glLinkProgram (shader_programme);

int matrix_location = glGetUniformLocation (shader_programme, "matrix");
glUseProgram (shader_programme);
glUniformMatrix4fv (matrix_location, 1, GL_FALSE, matrix);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is common problem to solve when moving from GL - fixed pipeline into modern "core" openGL.

In general you have to update matrices on your own each time you want to 'move' geometry.

```
glUseProgram(shader_id);
bind_textures();
bind_vaos_and_buffers();

matrix = math_library::createTranslationMatrix(x, y, z);
glUniformMatrix4fv (matrix_location, 1, GL_FALSE, matrix);
glDraw*(...);

matrix = math_library::createTranslationMatrix(x1, y1, z1);
glUniformMatrix4fv (matrix_location, 1, GL_FALSE, matrix);
glDraw*(...);
```

in general: each time you want to draw something: create a proper matrix, sent it to the active shader and then call a 'draw' command. Please **note** that that way **one** geometry data is used and we simply draw it several times using several different transformations.

`math_library` - can be a [glm library](http://glm.g-truc.net/) for instance

you can read a whole chapter about positioning and movement [here](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Positioning/Positioning.html)

Comment: Are you forced to make different VAOs. Since if I have 1,000,000 triangles. I don't want to create 1,000,000 VAOs if I want to be able to move the triangle independently from each other. The way your are doing it I would have to create a lot of VAOs.

Comment: @simplicity: How did you do it before? If you were changing matrices (ie: what push and pop *do*) in the middle of glBegin/glEnd, that's the *same thing* as issuing a bunch of draw calls.

Comment: @simplicity I changed my answer... "Please note that that way one geometry data is used and we simply draw it several times using several different transformations." we do not want to clone geometry of course.